# Spring Transaction Management in Multi-Thread?

Tags: spring, multithreading, transactions

Spring Transaction doesn't support multi-thread, so I try to manage transaction manually in Thread's run() method. But, It doesn't work!

I'd like to rollback each thread's run() method in below example when there's a exception throw inside it. (In below case, INSERT INTO UNKNOWN_TABLE)

My expected result is 'start, 1, 3, 5, end'.

And the actual result is 'start, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, end'.

Any reply is welcome! Thanks!

---

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource createDriverManagerDataSource() {

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:port/schema");
        dataSource.setUsername("xxxx");
        dataSource.setPassword("xxxx");

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate() {

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(createDriverManagerDataSource());

        return jdbcTemplate;

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        testService.test();

    }

}
```

---

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO TB_MYTEST(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('start', 'start')");

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            executorService.submit(new TestRunner(i));

        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO TB_MYTEST(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('end', 'end')");
    }

    private class TestRunner implements Runnable {

        private Integer id;

        public TestRunner(Integer id) {

            this.id = id;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try (Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {

                try {

                    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

                    String sqlString = String.format("INSERT INTO TB_MYTEST(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('%d', '%d')", id, id);
                    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlString);

                    if (id % 2 == 0) {
                        // Except the transaction been rollback when this.id is 2 or 4.
                        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO UNKNOWN_TABLE(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('no', 'no')");

                    }

                    connection.commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.err.println("Failure: UNKNOWN_TABLE");
                    connection.rollback();

                } finally {

                    connection.close();

                }

            } catch (SQLException e2) {

                e2.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work. You are trying to outsmart the framework, but what you actually do is introduce a connection leak (kind of). The `jdbcTemplate` uses a different connection then you are using, so setting the autocommit is useless. What you should do is use the `TransactionTemplate` and wrap the code in that, instead of messing around with the connection yourself. Also you are using Spring boot which autoconfigures the datasource, jdcbtemplate and transaction template, why do it yourself?

Comment: Thanks for telling me that jdbcTemplate uses a different connection then the connection which i create manually. I'm not using Spring Boot auto configuration just because i was copy the code from Spring Project. (I'd post my answer down below using Spring Boot auto configuration and transaction template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things with your code as you are trying to outsmart both Spring and Spring Boot. Instead of trying to do that, work with the frameworks instead of around them.

1. Ditch your `@Configuration` class and let Spring Boot do the configuration
2. Use `TransactionTemplate` instead of messing around with the (wrong!) `Connection` yourself.
3. Use the Spring `TaskExecutor`, configured by default, instead of manual access to a `Executor`.

Add this to your `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:port/schema
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
```

Instead of the messing around with the connection use a `TransactionTemplate`.

```
@@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final String SQL = "INSERT INTO TB_MYTEST(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES (?, ?)";
    private static final String ERROR_SQL = "INSERT INTO UNKNOWN_TABLE(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES (?, ?)";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner testRunner(JdbcTemplate jdbc, TransactionTemplate tx, TaskExecutor tasks) {
        return (args) -> {
            jdbc.update(SQL, "start", "start");
            IntStream.range(1, 6)
                    .forEach(id -> {
                        try {
                            tasks.execute(() -> tx.executeWithoutResult((s) -> {
                                jdbc.update(SQL, id, id);
                                if (id % 2 == 0) {
                                    jdbc.update(ERROR_SQL, "no", "no");
                                }
                            }));
                        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
            jdbc.update(SQL, "end", "end");
        };
    }
}
```

Something like the above would yield the result you want. Notice that you now use the `JdbcTemplate`, `TransactionTemplate` and `TaskExecutor` as provided by the frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

After refer to @M. Deinum answer, I have change my code to below and it meet's my needs.

---

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port/schema
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

---

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        testService.test();
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

---

TestService

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO TB_MYTEST(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('start', 'start')");

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            executorService.submit(new TestRunner(i));

        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO TB_MYTEST(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('end', 'end')");
    }

    private class TestRunner implements Runnable {

        private Integer id;

        public TestRunner(Integer id) {

            this.id = id;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

            transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

                @Override
                protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {

                    String sqlString = String.format("INSERT INTO TB_MYTEST(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('%d', '%d')", id, id);
                    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlString);

                    if (id % 2 == 0) {

                        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO UNKNOWN_TABLE(MYKEY, MYVALUE) VALUES ('no', 'no')");

                    }

                }

            });

        }

    }

}
```

---

With result 'start, 1, 3, 5, end'.